# VcXsrv full screen

Tags: scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

I have installed Ubuntu on my windows via wsl. I have followed this guide: https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-install-the-ubuntu-desktop-with-the-graphical-user-interface-in-wsl2-71f4b78431a4

Currently the GUI is being opened in frame, but i want to make it open in full screen mode. Is there any chance i can do it?

[screenshot of VcXsrv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6uog.png)
Here is the script to launch VcXsrv :

```
' define variables
dim application_object, shell_object, userprofile, command_object, standard_output_string

' create application object
set application_object = createobject("shell.application")

' create shell object
set shell_object = createobject("wscript.shell")

' store environment variable
username = shell_object.expandenvironmentstrings("%username%")

' run powershell in the background
application_object.shellexecute "powershell", "-file c:\users\" & username & "\.ubuntu\scripts\reload_vcxsrv.ps1", "", "", 0

' wait for powershell script to complete
wscript.sleep 3000

' create command object
set command_object = shell_object.exec("wsl genie --is-in-bottle")

' store standard output
standard_output = command_object.stdout.readall

' execute contents if shell is inside the genie container
if instr(standard_output, "inside") > 0 then
  
  ' run bash script
  shell_object.run "bash /mnt/c/users/" & username & "/.ubuntu/scripts/start_desktop.sh", 0

' execute contents if shell is outside the genie container   
else 
  
  ' run bash script
  shell_object.run "wsl genie -c bash /mnt/c/users/" & username & "/.ubuntu/scripts/start_desktop.sh", 0

end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, that doesn't look like the script that starts VcXsrv.  According to the blog post you referenced, that's found [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/david-littlefield/a78d8aad25c58408a4cd48147ac7615f/raw), and is:

```
# stop vcxsrv proccess that contains "0.0" in the program window title
get-process vcxsrv | where { $_.mainwindowtitle -like "*0.0*" } | stop-process

# start vcxsrv process in a large program window on display number one
start-process "c:\program files\vcxsrv\vcxsrv.exe" -argument ":0.0 -ac -nowgl -multimonitors -dpms"
```

Second, according to the [VcSrv docs](https://sourceforge.net/p/vcxsrv/wiki/Using%20VcXsrv%20Windows%20X%20Server/), the commandline option `-fullscreen` is what you are looking for.

Try modifying the script above and adding `-fullscreen` to the commandline.

Comment: thats awesome man! you're genius

Comment: You're welcome.  As a heads-up, I recommend `xrdp` for connecting to full-screen Linux desktops under WSL.  It has the advantage of capturing all keystrokes (like Alt-Tab, etc.) correctly.